# Image zooming using System.Drawing.Image

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

I took the following code for rotating an image from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txebzd3d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) link. To use this code in my test application, first I made a win32 C++ console application. Then I put the following program into my .cpp file.
I downloaded system.drawing.dll and put this dll in the folder where my application is made.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"

#using <system.drawing.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Drawing;

int main()
{
Image^ image = Image::FromFile("SampleImage.jpg");
image->RotateFlip( RotateFlipType::Rotate90FlipNone );
image->Save("SampleImage_rotated.jpg");
return 0;
}
```

When I am building the application (on MSVC 2010 , Windows 7, 32 bit), its working as 
intended and I am getting a new 90 degree rotated image.

I liked this code very much, since it is the shortest  code I found for rotating an Image.

My questions are:

1- Can I use this same code inside an application which is written in C++ using 
     winform? Or do I have to do some kind of conversion ?

2- Using the same class i.e System.Drawing.Image how do I implement zooming or scaling of the image?

Many thanks for your precious time replying to my query.

Comment: Your code (the method body) will port as is assuming you are using C++. You will have to do some conversion (syntax mainly) if you use C#

Comment: @ChrisF gr8. Any pointers on question no 2?

Comment: You did **not** create a "win32 C++ console application".  This is C++/CLI code.  So no trouble doing this with a C++/CLI Winforms app or using System::Drawing.  Zoom by using Graphics::ScaleTransform in a Paint event handler.